# Background field Method in non-linear $\sigma$-model: Covariantized Taylor series of geodesic between fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems, geodesics, covariance, sigma-models

In [this](https://inspirehep.net/literature/10232) paper, the authors try to develop an expansion of the non-linear $\sigma$-model action with covariant terms called the Background field method. We have a "fixed" background field $\phi: \Sigma \to M$, $\Sigma$ being a spacetime and $M$ being a target space manifold. It is defined a perturbed field by $\phi^i + \pi^i$. The problem is that the taylor polynomials of a tensor at $\phi^i + \pi^\mu$ around $\phi^i$ are not covariant.

The authors construct a geodesic $\lambda:[0,1] \to M $ with $\lambda^i(0) = \phi^i, \, \lambda^i(1) = \phi^i + 
 \pi^i, \, \dot{\lambda}^i(0) = \xi^i.$ If we apply the geodesic equation successively in the Taylor series of $\lambda(t)$ around $t=0$ we get

\begin{align}
\tag1 \lambda^i(t) &= \phi^i + \xi^i t + \frac{1}{2}\ddot{\gamma}^i(0)t^2 + \frac{1}{3!}\dddot{\gamma}^i(0)t^3 + \cdots \\
&= \phi^i + \xi^i t - \frac{1}{2}\Gamma^i_{jk}(\phi)\xi^j\xi^k t^2 - \frac{1}{3!}\nabla_m\Gamma^i_{jk}(\phi)\xi^j \xi^k \xi^m + \cdots,
\end{align}
where $\nabla_m$ applied to christoffel symbols means covariant differentiation w.r.t. lower indices only. The construction of $\lambda$ gives us the Riemann normal coordinates. In normal coordinates we have that $\lambda^i(t) = \xi^i t$, which by $(1)$ implies that  $\partial_{(i_1}\partial_{i_2}\cdots \Gamma^i_{i_{n-1}i_n)}(\phi)=0$. This lead us to some identities such as

$\tag2 \partial_{i_1}\Gamma^i _{i_2 i_3}(\phi) = \frac{1}{3} \left( R^i_{\, i_2 i_1 i_3}(\phi) + R^i_{\, i_3 i_1 i_2}(\phi) \right), \, \text{in normal coordinates}.$

In the paragraph above equation $(2.17)$ in the paper, it is said that

> The other necessary ingredient of the background field method is the expansion of
> $\partial_\mu(\phi^i + \pi^i)$. This is a vector, and its expansion in the normal coordinate system is
> obtained by differentiation of (2.5) at t = 1.$$\tag{2.17} \partial_\mu(\phi^i + \pi^i) = \partial_\mu \phi^i + \partial_\mu \xi^i - \left(\frac{1}{2} \partial_j\Gamma^i_{i_1 i_2}(\phi)\xi^{i_1}\xi^{i_2}  +  \cdots\right)\partial_\mu\phi^j$$
> One then uses definitions $(2.6)$ together with the normal coordinate conditions $(2.7)$
> and $(2.8)$ and also $(2.11)$-$(2.13)$ to derive the tensorial result
> $$\tag{2.18} \partial_\mu(\phi^i + \pi^i) = \partial_\mu \phi^i + D_\mu \xi^i + \left( \frac{1}{3} R^i_{\,k_1 k_2 j \xi^{k_1} \xi^{k_2}  }+\cdots\right)\partial_\mu \phi^j,$$
> where $D_\mu \xi^i = \partial_\mu \xi^i + \Gamma^i_{jk} \xi^j \partial_\mu \phi^k.$

1. It is not clear to me how to get $(2.18)$ from $(2.17)$ by using only normal coordinates, because in these coordinates $\phi^i \equiv 0 \implies \partial_\mu \pi^i = \partial_\mu \xi^i$ in normal coordinates.
2. Equation $(2.17)$ if not wrong, have some terms ommited, because we should have a term like $\Gamma^i_{i_1 i_2}(\phi)\partial_\mu \xi^{i_1}\xi^{i_2}$ for instance.
3. The most confusing thing to me is how the authors got the term $D_\mu\xi$ which looks like a covariant derivative.

I'd appreciate any help with these problems.